# My MacBook shut down while uploading an iOS app through Xcode to the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, app-store, archive

I am trying to upload an app to App Store. After archiving, the upload process starts fine and it takes sometime then the MacBook shut down and of course the uploading is canceled.

if anyone has an idea how to fix this, it will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know **why** it shut down?  (Console logs?)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but the issue was wired, it was something related my internet provider and when I changed it, it works fine